# Install and run containers on Slurm HPC

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I have an hpc slurm on ubuntu and I want to install docker or docker rootles. But I can't find anything on official sites, so how could I install docker on a slurm cluster and run containers or if you know another container tool I would be grateful!

Thanks!

How to install docker on slurm hpc?

Answer (score 0):

Most cluster management teams will avoid Docker because of the risks of privilege escalation it offers and will recommend Singularity/Apptainer, which is a container engine specifically designed for HPC clusters and mostly compatible with Docker files.

Comment: Thanks for alternative. I will read about this